# How can open a spreadsheet without running onOpen script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apparently I have made a mistake while coding an onOpen script.
Now, when I open the spreadsheet, the onOpen code runs, and it impossible to do anything on the spreadsheet, the script stays in progress and no one can access the spreadsheet to wrote / navigate /scroll or whatever.

Anyway to open a spreadsheet with this kind of script "off" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to https://script.google.com/home and find the script to open it and fix it without needing to open the spreadsheet.